# MS updates to components that are not installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, .net-framework

I cannot be the only one, who experiences this: 
Windows Update keeps recommending me updates to components (.NET framework of different versions, parts of MS Office), which I think I do not have on my machine. Having been tweaking the Win OSs for fifteen years I shouldn't think I am inexperienced, so it is embarrasing.

Right now, after a fresh OS install I have done my best to remove all .NET that had been pre-packaged with the OEM Win7 HE, 64bit. I have removed all v4.0 bits in the Programs list, applied the official dotnet cleanup tool and still am getting recommendations of .NET 3.5.1 security updates in Windows Update.

Is it possible that bits of .NET are purposely covered up? Could any of you gurus comment on (1) where I should look for the "hidden" remnants of .NET and (2) whether it is reasonable to ignore the updates as long as one is convinced that the framework to-be-updated is not present?

Many thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Even without the roles being installed, Windows still has it available so it can be added at any time.  I would assume that's why it keeps getting updates...  I wouldn't worry about it, a lot of applications use the framework nowadays.  As for Office, I know that some of the updates for it also affect Windows itself, which would be my only guess on that front as well.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 isnt a program that is (un)installed from "Add/Remove Programs."  Its a Windows Feature that is enabled/disabled.

From the Control Panel/Programs select "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and see if .NET 3.5 is enabled.  If it is, then thats why Windows wants to update it.

If you disable the feature, you will no longer receive updates for it.

The next question is why you want to disable .NET?  Although it isnt necessary, there are a lot of applications out there that rely on it.